# WordPress 5.3 update causes media library file upload to break - Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: plugins, media-library, core

So after updating to WP 5.3 I can no longer use the file upload to choose files to add. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at g.cleanup (backbone.min.js:1)
```

Error in console:
[image]

How it shows when I try to choose an image:
[image]

I have the Classic Editor plugin installed so I can use it the classic way. I have disabled all other unnecessary plugins but the problem still persists. It's only happened since the new WP core update to 5.3 yesterday.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Having the same issue, glad I'm not alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so what worked for me was upgrading my PHP version to 7.2 and that did the job.

I was using 7.0 before.

Comment: Nah, at least for me. I've been using PHP 7.3, and having this issue, it seems it's a conflict between Classic Editor and Yoast SEO https://wordpress.org/support/topic/strange-behaviour-after-upgrade-to-wp-5-3/ and this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/5-3-update-now-yoast-not-working/ , since the outcome and error is same, I believe it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. In my case it was the Enhanced Media Library plugin, which looks as though it has not been updated in some time. I deactivated it, and all is good.

Comment: Same here. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yep, it is. Thanks for the help. And this description of Enhanced Media Library says a lot: "Last Updated: 2 years ago. Requires WordPress Version: 4.5 or higher. Compatible up to: 4.9.15".

Comment: Added EML 3 years ago. During a sweeping upgrade to Gutenberg this week, the image block would fail when loading an image. Disabling this plugin worked. This should be the solution.

Answer (score -2):

My problem was with ŧhe Enhanced Media Library plugin and this solution worked for me https://wordpress.org/support/topic/quick-fix-for-upload-breakage-after-wp-5-3/

Comment: Can you include the solution in your answer? A link offsite isn't an answer. You can link offsite to support your answer but the answer needs to be understandable without leaving the site. Edit your answer to include the solution using the edit link underneath the answer text